# Can all Destiny 2 users play together, regardless of edition?

Tags: xbox-one, destiny-2

I am looking to buy the standard edition of Destiny 2 while my friend has the Deluxe Edition, both on xbox.

Will I be able to play with him? Will some content be locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still play the game together.  The Deluxe version include the following:

> - Destiny 2 Base Game
> - Destiny 2 Expansion Pass: Get access to both Expansion I and Expansion II, offering brand new story missions, cooperative
>     activities, competitive multiplayer, and a wealth of new weapons,
>     armor, and gear.
> - Premium Digital Content:
>
>   - Legendary Sword
>   - Legendary Player Emote
>   - Cabal Empire Themed Emblem

[(Source)](https://www.destinythegame.com/buy)

The deluxe edition pre-purchases the first two expansions essentially.  You can always buy those separately.  If you don't purchase them, you won't be able to take part in any of the content that comes with those expansions.  You won't have access to the "Premium Digital Content" either, but that shouldn't impact being able to play with one another.

Comment: At the moment, only expansion one is out.  So that will be the other stuff you won't be able to take part in, unless you purchase it for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Does that mean that Destiny 2 Base Game does not have competitive multiplayer or cooperative activities?

Or is it referring to the 'brand new'?

Comment: @Childishforlife when it says "Base Game" it means the game without any expansions.  Multiplayer is not an expansion in any way.

Comment: my apologies what I meant was the Expansion Pass says "Get access to both Expansion I and Expansion II, offering brand new story missions, cooperative activities, competitive multiplayer." 
From my first read through it seems like you need the Expansion I and II to get cooperative activities *and* multiplayer.

Comment: Any content that shipped with the base game last September you'll both be able to play. If you don't buy the expansions or expansion pass, then you can't play the new story mission, strikes, or crucible maps (there are separate playlists for these).